# android gallery layout

Tags: android

What type of layout i should use?

What layout elements I need?

```
__________________________________________________
|list_item  |                                    | 
|list_item  |                                    |             
|list_item  |                                    |
|list_item  | details with images on item click  |
|list_item  |                                    |
|list_item  |                                    |
|list_item  |                                    |
```

Comment: Normal listview with imageview or listview with viewswitcher if you want animation.

Comment: Choose `Relative` or `Frame` layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `LinearLayout` -horizontal for parent, `LinearLayout` -vertical for left-child, and anything you need for right child. Just remember to set the

```
android: weight_sum
```

so your left child have proportion of screen.